# 401 Unauthorized error when trying to generate an embed token for PowerBI report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi, postman

I am attempting to embed a PowerBI report into my web app. I have followed both Microsoft documentation and online tutorials (specifically https://www.kieferconsulting.com/2021/11/01/how-to-embed-power-bi-content-in-a-react-application/).

I am taking the approach of using a Service Principal rather than a Master User. I have created an Azure App and am using a Security Group to act as the Service Principal.

I've added the Service Principal to the PowerBI Workspace I want to use as an Admin user.

I ran into issues making the requests via my Node app and have been trying to use Postman to check the requests are valid.

I've been able to Authorize my app and get a valid token:

[image: Successful Azure Auth]

Using this token, I've also been able to get the embed URL:

[image: Use token to get Embed URL successfully]

But, when I try then get the Embed Token, using the same Auth Token in the previous step:

[image: Error Generating Embed Token]

I get the following error:

401 Unauthorized

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
        "pbi.error": {
            "code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
            "parameters": {},
            "details": [],
            "exceptionCulprit": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal) for embedding using a service principal:

> My Workspace isn't supported when using service principal.

While the report I was trying to embed was not located in "My Workspace", its underlying dataset was located there.

Once I moved the dataset to a different workspace, I no longer received the Unauthorized errors I was previously seeing

Comment: Man, thank you! I spent a whole day checking my Azure AD settings and Power Bi workspace and admin settings, when this was the issue...